# Does pipexec create some subprocesses?

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout, stdin, ps

I am using pipexec tool to manage communication between processes.
My task requires me to retrieve ids of processes that communicate.

Example:

```
pipexec -- [ A ./cmd1 ] [ B ./cmd2 ] "{A:1>B:0}" "{B:1>A:0}" &
```

Then:

```
ps --ppid xxxx
```

Where xxxx is pid of pipexec process.
Can I be sure that there will be exactly 2 processes displayed or is there possibility that pipexec run some internal process at some point of running?

Comment: Can you please detail why you need the pids of the children? Is there some feature missing in pipexec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`pipexec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/pipexec.1.html) man page:

> pipexec  creates  an  arbitrary network (directed graph) of processes
>   and pipes in between - even cycles are possible.  It overcomes the
>   shortcomings of shells that are typically only able to create non
>   cyclic trees.
>
> pipexec also monitors all it's child processes and is able to restart
>   the whole network of processes and pipes if one crashes.  Therefore
>   pipexec can be used in SYSV-init  or  systemd configuration to run a
>   network of processes.

So, it's possible that in case of failures when `pipexec` restarts the the "network", it could create more processes than you could know.
But assuming there are no failures, it appears that `pipexec` creates just the number of processes you have specified. Experimentally, I see:

```
$ ps -af
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
usr  6531 29605  0 13:02 pts/9    00:00:00 pipexec -- [ A /bin/sleep 30 ] [ B /bin/sleep 40 ]
usr  6532  6531  0 13:02 pts/9    00:00:00 /bin/sleep 30
usr  6533  6531  0 13:02 pts/9    00:00:00 /bin/sleep 40
```

when running:

```
pipexec -- [ A /bin/sleep 30 ] [ B /bin/sleep 40 ]
```

This may or may not be universally true. But I couldn't find anything in the documentation that says anything on this.

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what I managed to find out by myself. I was hoping that someone will be able to tell me that if I assume no failures there will or will not be created any additional process.

Comment: Since, it's not documented, I'd say it could, in theory, change if they rewrite the code or introduce some other features without notification. If you think about it, this sort of expectation seems rather unusual (no additional procesess) in normal uses of pipexec. So the only way left is to look at the [source code](https://github.com/flonatel/pipexec) to be sure that the current implementation doesn't create additional processes.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of pipexec (>=2.6.0) introduces event logging using json formatted event descriptions. The pids of the children is one piece of information that is given.

```
$ pipexec -j 1 -- [ A /bin/sleep 30 ] [ B /bin/sleep 60 ]
{"timestamp":1655793546,"pipexec_pid":61855,"id":1,"type":"exec","serverity":"info","message":"New child forked","command":"A","command_pid":"61856"}
{"timestamp":1655793546,"pipexec_pid":61855,"id":1,"type":"exec","serverity":"info","message":"New child forked","command":"B","command_pid":"61857"}
```

Only the important events are shown - there is also the possibility to get the exit status of a child.

(Note: I'm the author of pipexec.)